# Floating div vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/vnnmuy4y/ -
https://jsfiddle.net/vnnmuy4y/1/

As you can see I have a few `div` elements and each one of them has different, unknown dimensions. In order to stack them side by side, I use `float:left;`, which does seem to work pretty well, except if I add so many `div`'s that they span to a second line.

In this case, there can be a space, where the div below could fit and could move up, but it doesn't, in order to maintain the lines.

I don't know if it makes any sense, but think of it as something like `float:up;` :-)

Any ideas on how to achieve this in CSS?

Comment: Would you like your divs to fit together like puzzle pieces?

Comment: Another question for [**masonry.js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Yes, I'd like the 'div' elements to fit like puzzle pieces. Will have a look at the links provided by others and update.

Comment: Masonry does fix the problem as long as all elements are of the same width. Is there any solution that works on both width and height?